# Unix command output being displayed after next shell prompt

Tags: c, shell, unix, command

I'm working on a shell written in C for a school project, though this question is much less intensive than you might think. The issue is that when I type a command, for example `ls`, the output is displayed after the next `shell>` prompt that shows at the beginning of the overall shell loop. The shell looks like:

```
shell>ls 
shell>Debug  shell.c
```

My code:

```
int main(){

    char line[255];

    while (1){
            printf("shell>");
            fgets(line, 255, stdin);
            if (strcmp(line, "exit\n") == 0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                char* args[255];
                size_t n = 0;
                for (char* ptr = strtok(line, " \n"); ptr; ptr = strtok(NULL, " \n")){
                    if (n >= 255){
                        break;
                    }
                    args[n++] = ptr;
                }
                args[n++] = NULL;
                for (size_t i = 0; i != n; ++i){
                    //printf("Token %zu is '%s'.\n", i, args[i]);
                }
                int pid = fork();
                if (pid == 0){
                    //child process code
                    int flag = execvp(args[0], args);
                    if (flag < 0){
                        perror("execvp failed");
                    }
                }
                else{
                    //parent process code
                    pid_t wait_pid(pid);
                }
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All other errors aside, what's causing the output to be displayed this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pid_t wait_pid(pid);` is wrong, it does not call `wait_pid`. When calling function, you don't specify the return *type*. Instead, try:

```
pid_t result_pid = wait_pid(pid);
// add error handling etc here, check man page for return value details
```

---

And since you don't actually wait for the child process, the parent proceeds to print the prompt immediately, giving you the output you see.